# Jquery target all divs on page with duplicate classnames without providing specific class

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery Question for a rails app... I have the following code (simplified), where classes are generated dynamically:

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
```

In the above example, I need to find both divs with class "one" and both divs with class "four" for the purpose of applying unique styling to those four divs.

In the actual code, there are far more than 4 possible classes, which creates my issue (There are closer to 30-40 different classes).

The set of possible classes is only going to grow and change with this application, and the jquery can't be tied to any specific class or set of classes... It needs to account for an infinite set of classes.

Without specifying a specific class or set of classes, such as .one, .two, .three, .four, etc., how could I find all divs on a page that share a class with another div, regardless of what that class is?

Comment: Loop through all divs, get their class(es). Check the length of the result when selecting div elements with that class. Keep a “cache” of classes, so that you don’t needlessly check classes again, that you already examined. (Or specify in more detail, what you actually need this for …)

Comment: You'd have to parse the whole document, and create a map of classes to elements. It would be quite heavy to do, could you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: @CBroe, the need for this is as follows. I'm working on a rails app that allows users to build pages with widgets of different types, or classes. If a users creates, let's say, two photo widgets, my client wishes to differentiate the two by adding a different color background  so the widgets are clearly separate.

Comment: I don’t see any reason why that could not be handled server-side already … if the app realizes that two widgets of the same kind are output on the same page, then have it set f.e. and additional class that gives the second one different colors …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite heavy, and basically what @CBroe meant:

```
$(function() {
    $("div[class]").each(function() {
        var num = $("."+this.className).length;
        if (num > 1) alert(this.className + " is duplicate!");
    });
});
```

If your elements have multiple classes, you need to split them at the space and iterate over that as well.

Comment: this is preforming as expected, displaying an alert for each duplicate class... Could you modify the if statement to add a class of "duplicate-class" to each appropriate div? If so, winner winner chicken dinner. Much appreciated.

Comment: @gold9design you mean `if (num > 1) $(this).addClass("duplicate");`?

Comment: that doesn't work... This slightly modified version is adding the class of duplicate to all divs, regardless of whether or not its a duplicate... if (num > 1) { $(this).addClass("duplicate"); } ... Maybe something similar to this.className instead of this would do the trick?

Comment: @Shishir, do you have any idea why this would be working in isolation, but not in the context of the app I'm working on? The main difference is that I'm still hitting all divs, regardless of how many times the class appears. I know it is going to be tough to know for sure without seeing the codebase, but any ideas would be great.

Comment: @gold9design, Unfortunately, I can't say anything without looking at your code. It could be something as simple as a minor typo. I hope you find what you are looking for. Once you do, please let us know what it was. Cheers!

Comment: @Shishir, do you have time for a screencast so I can show you the code base? If so, please email me at info@gold9design.com. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> how could I find all divs on a page that share a class with another div

This implies that you already have a specific div (for example: #someDiv) which has some classes, and you want to find all divs that have one or more classes in common with #someDiv

I hope I am understanding your problem correctly.

Try this:

```
var classList = $('#someDiv').attr('class').split(/\s+/);
for(var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
  classList[i] = '.' + classList[i];
}
var selector = classList.join(', ');
$(selector).css('color', '#FF0000');
```

That last line basically selects all divs that share any class with our initial div.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Cheers!

Comment: This is super super close... The only issue is that it is only using the first child to compare to the rest of the children. So if the first div has a class of "one" and so does the third, divs one and three are targeted. But if divs two and four both have the class of "two", they are not targeted.